# Pandas Detect Non-Numberic Data types

Tags: pandas

I need to detect and prevent any non-numeric data getting into my dataframe.

example:

```
     value       in       out     transf      inc        buy
0   208372  4206.84   4692.22     215976   725.41  105339.92
1      abs     0.00   1270.28      13602  1151.29       0.00
2   230172     0.00   1930.40      21539  1938.59       0.00
3   394391     0.00  11517.96     174320  1517.06  170032.09
4   382101     0.00   2962.82          0  3001.14   10000.00
```

print(df.dtypes) gives me this:

```
value         object
in           float64
out          float64
transf         int64
inc          float64
buy          float64
dtype: object
```

So how do I detect if there are any non-number (float64, int64) datatype?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pd.to_numeric`, it will change the non numeric to NaN. Then we just need detect the NaN with `isna` or `isnull`

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
      value       in       out  transf      inc        buy
0  208372.0  4206.84   4692.22  215976   725.41  105339.92
1       NaN     0.00   1270.28   13602  1151.29       0.00
2  230172.0     0.00   1930.40   21539  1938.59       0.00
3  394391.0     0.00  11517.96  174320  1517.06  170032.09
4  382101.0     0.00   2962.82       0  3001.14   10000.00
```

Let us add

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').isnull().any().any()
```

If `True` should be a problem , if `False` should be ok

Comment: the data is coming in via an excel that the user is submitting.  I need to bounce an error message back at them.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using np.isreal? Here we can get a list of columns that do not have all real numbers.

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if not df[c].map(np.isreal).all()]
```

And this will print out the problem columns for users.

```
if len(cols) != 0:
    print('The following columns have non-real number values:')
    for c in cols:
        print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the row number of the non numeric data you can use this:

```
print('Following row indices contains the string type value')
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if any(isinstance(x,str) for x in row):
        print(ind+1)
```